# How to remove WIP flag from Gerrit changeset with Git

Tags: git, gerrit

I've pushed a work-in-progress (WIP) changeset to Gerrit by pushing to `refs/for/master%wip`, [as per the documentation](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/user-upload.html#wip).

The documentation also states that one can remove the WIP flag from a changeset by pushing it to `refs/for/master%ready`, but Gerrit consistently rejects the push with the error

```
! [remote rejected] mybranch -> refs/for/master%ready (no new changes)
```

Force-pushing doesn't help either.

Is there a way to remove the WIP flag via Git without introducing artificial changes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't set the WIP flag using the "git push" command without pushing a new patchset.

You can, of course, use the graphical interface or you can post to /changes/CHANGE-ID/ready to set the WIP flag using REST. See more info [here](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/rest-api-changes.html#set-ready-for-review).

Answer (score 6):

In case you don't have anything to push, but you want to mark your commit as ready, you can execute the following commands:

```
git commit --amend --no-edit
git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master%ready ==> replace "master" with your branch name.
```

Comment: Be aware that, of course, this creates a new patchset but without any changes.

Comment: To add, the [docs](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/intro-user.html) currently say: To mark the change as ready for review, append `%ready` to your push request.

  `$ git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master%ready`

(I think in older versions the WIP state would be dropped even without this)

Answer (score 3):

You can always remove flag using GUI by pressing start review button.